# Passing a number to parseFloat() instead of string

Tags: javascript, json, numbers, parsefloat

In my code, the value of a particular var can originate from any one of a number of different json sources.  For some of those sources, the json element concerned will be a string (e.g. `"temp": "10.2"`), while for other sources the json element will already be a float (e.g. `"temp": 10.2`).

Does it do any harm (is anything likely to break) if I just pass the json element (from whatever source) through a `parseFloat()`, even if it's already a float?  It seems to work; I'm just thinking about good/bad practice and possible breakage in future or on a different platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call parseFloat() on a float or a string without any problems.  If it is a float already, it's converted to a string first, and then to a float again, so it's a little less efficient, but it shouldn't matter too much.

You should still check the result for NaN, in case there's something unexpected in the data.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate method to convert any datatype to a number is to use the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function:

> In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the `new` operator),
>   `Number` can be used to perform a type conversion.

```
Number("1234")    // 1234
Number(1234)      // 1234
```

This method differs from [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) in these ways at least:

1. Number function does not perform "double-conversion" if the input is already a number ([ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-9.3))

   - Parse float converts the input to a string then extracts the number ([ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.1.2.3))
2. Number function returns common sense values for most datatypes e.g. `Number(true)` yields 1

   - Parse float uses the string value of input so `parseFloat(true)` tries to parse number from `"true"` and yields NaN
3. Number function fails when input string is an invalid number e.g. `Number("123abc")` yields NaN

   - Parse float tries to *parse* as much of a number as possible e.g. `parseFloat("123abc")` yields 123

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the value is always a valid number, you should use `Number(stringOrNumber)`.

If you need some additional safety using `parseFloat()` you could also write your own function which is also performance optimized:

```
function toFloat(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' ? value : parseFloat(value);
}
```

I also created a [jsPerf test case](https://jsperf.com/parsefloat-with-number-or-string/) that shows the performance is >30% better than the plain `parseFloat()` for a 1:1 ratio between strings and numbers as input values.

Answer (score 0):

Nope there is no problem with passing a number to it

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) says as long as it can be converted to a number, nothing breaking should happen.

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat returns NaN.

As an alternative, you could use the unary operator `+` which does basically the same thing as `parseFloat` and also returns `NaN` if it didn't work.

For instance:

```
var myFloat = +('10.5');
var myOtherFloat = parseFloat('10.5', 10);
var alreadyAFloat = parseFloat(10.5, 10);

console.log(myFloat === myOtherFloat && myOtherFloat === alreadyAFloat); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Wether it's a `float` or a `String` using `parseFloat()` is much safer to avoid all kind of errors.

As you said it will always work, but if you enforce it to be a float you will avoid getting any Exception.

For Example:

> Both `parseFloat('10.2', 10)` and `parseFloat(10.2, 10)` will work
>   perfectly and will give you the same result which is `10.2`.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I can't see this being a problem what so ever, to be honest I would always use the parsefloat() for one reason, and that is safety. You can never be to sure what may happen, so always predict the worse :D